# CSS: Floating image inside left then right then left again inside even/odd <articles>

Tags: css, css-selectors

It's probably easiest to explain if I post some code:

```
<article>
   <img class="service_pic" src="image.png" title="UNFILLED" /> <!-- I WANT THIS (ODD) IMAGE FLOATED RIGHT -->
   <div class="service_text">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
   </div>
</article>

<article>
   <img class="service_pic" src="image.png" title="UNFILLED" /> <!-- I WANT THIS (EVEN) ONE FLOATED LEFT -->
   <div class="service_text">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
   </div>
</article>

<article>
   <img class="service_pic" src="image.png" title="UNFILLED" /> <!-- I WANT THIS (ODD) ONE FLOATED RIGHT AGAIN) -->
   <div class="service_text">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
   </div>
</article>
```

Thanks!

I am aware of nth-child and nth-of-type but I don't know how to implement them. I know that I could theoretically add .left and .right to each service_pic and service_text but thats a lot of repetitive code. And its hard coded and must be edited every time a new  is added.

Comment: Use `article:nth-child(even) img` and `(odd)` to target your images.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
article:nth-child(odd){
float: right;
}

article:nth-child(even){
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @[cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4733161/cloned) suggested in comment, you can select odd-numbered articles with `article:nth-child(odd)` (or `article:nth-child(2n+1)`). If you want to select odd-numbered articles, you can use `article:nth-child(even)` (or `article:nth-child(2n)`).

Here I used a flex container to change the image order.

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 10px;
}

article .service_text {
  padding: 10px;
}

article:nth-child(2n+1) img {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img class="service_pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200" title="UNFILLED" />
  <!-- I WANT THIS (ODD) IMAGE FLOATED RIGHT -->
  <div class="service_text">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="service_pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" title="UNFILLED" />
  <!-- I WANT THIS (EVEN) ONE FLOATED LEFT -->
  <div class="service_text">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <img class="service_pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" title="UNFILLED" />
  <!-- I WANT THIS (ODD) ONE FLOATED RIGHT AGAIN) -->
  <div class="service_text">
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <p>CONTENT</p>
  </div>
</article>
```